# Scraping using beautiful soup: find class to add information in pandas

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would like to know how to extract information on year start from this website:

https://web.archive.org/details/www.stackoverflow.com

I have a few websites to check in a pandas column, for example:

```
URL                                     Popularity
www.stackoverflow.com                       8.5
www.web.archive.com                         5.4
...
```

I would need to create a new column in my dataset with the age of URL, i.e.

```
URL                                     Popularity            Y
www.stackoverflow.com                       8.5             2004   
www.web.archive.com                         5.4             2001
...
```

By inspecting the webpage, I know that I need to look at  `input min`, as shown below:

```
<input min="2004" max="2020" class="form-control" name="year_end" type="number" value="2004">
```

I tried as follows:

```
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 import requests

 main_url = 'https://web.archive.org/details/www.stackoverflow.com'
 response = requests.get(main_url)
 soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
```

I should use find_all to find the class I am interested in:

```
my_list = soup.find_all(attrs={'input min','class':'form-control'})
```

but the problem is that it does not scrape the age.

Can you please point me to the right direction?
Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you need from that page? There's no `popularity` field on the URL you posted.

Comment: Popularity is a field in my dataframe. What I need to get from the webpage is start year, i.e. min year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the lowest year, you can use this script (the page loads the data via javascript, so BeatifulSoup doesn't see it):

```
import json
import requests


urls = [
    'www.stackoverflow.com',
    'www.web.archive.com',  
]

api_url = 'https://web.archive.org/__wb/search/metadata'

for url in urls:
    data = requests.get(api_url, params={'q': url}).json()

    # uncomment this to see all data:
    # print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

    min_year = min(data['urls'], key=int)
    print(url, min_year)
```

Prints:

```
www.stackoverflow.com 2004
www.web.archive.com 2003
```

---

EDIT: Pseudo-code how to add min_years to existing dataframe:

```
api_url = 'https://web.archive.org/__wb/search/metadata'

list_of_min_years = []
for url in df['urls']:
    data = requests.get(api_url, params={'q': url}).json()
    min_year = min(data['urls'], key=int)
    list_of_min_years.append(min_year)

df['Y'] = list_of_min_years
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer and helping me. May I ask you how to add min_year in an existing dataframe? I have tried with `df['Y']=min_year`, but the field is empty in my df

Comment: @Math You can add min_year to a list and then do `df['Y'] = list_of_min_years`

Comment: Thanks Andrej.  Where does  list_of_min_years come from? Is it min_year?

Comment: @Math See my edit - I've added pseudo-code how to add min_year to existing dataframe.